# How to deploy the IEX API

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

How do I deploy the IEX API as I keep on getting the error "forbidden", even though I have token access

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'iex', start, end,\n
access_key = <key>)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
df = df.drop("Symbol", axis=1)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/c0uq3j/cs50_pset8_finance_api_to_iextrading_has_changed/